# Entity Framework "WHERE IN" style for Many-To-Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following tables (simplified):

```
Calendar                   CalendarItemAssociation          CalendarItem
--------                   -----------------------          ------------
CalendarId (PK)            CalendarId (PK)                  CalendarItemId (PK)
                           CalendarItemId(PK)
```

Using Entity Framework 4, I am required to pull a list of `CalendarItems` by providing a list of `CalendarIds`.

In T-SQL term this is what I'd write:

```
SELECT c.* FROM Calendar a INNER JOIN
              CalendarItemAssociation b ON a.CalendarId = b.CalendarId INNER JOIN
              CalendarItem c on b.CalendarItemId = c.CalendarItemId
WHERE a.CalendarId IN (1,2,3,4)
```

I have took references from a few solutions, the main ideas are like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx). However, they deal with single-to-many relationships and I can't seem to fill the gap.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the suggestions below, at the end of the day I derived my own syntax which kind of solved the problem, but I am not sure if this will result in any performance issues, this is my final code:

```
var items = ae.t_CalendarItemAssociation.Where(cia => calendars.Contains(cia.CalendarId)).Select(cia => cia.t_CalendarItem)
                    .Where(ci => date >= ci.StartDate.Date && date <= ci.EndDate.Date);
```

(The date comparison is another criteria that I needs to put in in order to return my preferred items).

Comment: Are you using a code first approach?

Comment: Nope, the context is updated from an existing DB.

Comment: Then you don't have to do any of this what so ever. Entity Framework knows that it need's to absorb the Junction table in this instance, the [CalendarItemAssociation] table and  will create a navigational property. Calendar,CalendarItemAssociations . This is how EF works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different linq query, which looks more like the original SQL:

```
var ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var query = (from c in db.Calendars
             join cia in db.CalendarItemAssociations on c.CalendarId equals cia.CalendarId
             join ci in db.CalendarItems on cia.CalendarItemId equals ci.CalendarItemId
             where ids.Contains(c.CalendarId)
             select ci);
```

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ you have to turn it inside out and put the ids in an array:

```
var ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4};

var query = 
from ci in CalendarItems
where ids.Contains(i => i == ci.CalendarItemAssociation
  .SelectMany(cim => cim.Calendar.Id))
slect ci
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, my problem here is that CalendarItemAssociate is of `ICollection` type in my entity (as it's a one-to-many relationship) and thus I can't do a `ci.CalendarItemAssociation.Calendar.Id`.

Comment: That can be solved with `SelectMany()`, see my edit.